# Address Out of bounds error when reading xml

Tags: c++, xml, linux, xml-parsing, redhat

I am getting a weird segfault when using libxml to parse a file. This code worked previously when I compiled it as a 32bit application. I changed it to a 64 bit application and it stops working.

The seg fault comes in at "if (xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *) "servers"))"

cur->name is a const xmlChar * and it points to an address that says its out out bounds. But when I debug and go to that memory location, that data is correct.

```
int XmlGetServers()
{
xmlDocPtr doc;
xmlNodePtr cur;

doc = xmlParseFile("Pin.xml");
if (doc == NULL)
{
    std::cout << "\n Pin.xml not parsed successfully." << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
cur = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

if (cur == NULL)
{
    std::cout << "\n Pin.xml is empty document." << std::endl;
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    return -1;
}
if (xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *) "servers"))
{
    std::cout << "\n ERROR: Pin.xml of the wrong type, root node != servers." << std::endl;
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    return -1;
}
}
```

Before cur is initialized the name parameter is

```
Name : name
    Details:0xed11f72000007fff <Address 0xed11f72000007fff out of bounds>
```

After cur is initialized the name parameter is

```
Name : name
    Details:0x64c43000000000 <Address 0x64c43000000000 out of bounds>
```

Referenced XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<servers>

<server_info>

    <server_name>Server1</server_name>

    <server_ip>127.0.0.1</server_ip> 

    <server_data_port>9000</server_data_port> 

</server_info>

<server_info>

    <server_name>Server2</server_name> 

    <server_ip>127.0.0.1</server_ip> 

    <server_data_port>9001</server_data_port> 

</server_info>

</servers>
```

System:

OS: Redhat Enterprise Linux 6.4 64-bit

GCC: 4.4.7-3

packages: libxml2-2.7.6-8.el6_3.4.x86_64

Comment: Do you have the 64bit version of libxml?

Comment: yes libxml2-2.7.6-8.el6_3.4.x86_64

Comment: Have you tried running the application using valgrind, like Sam Varshavchik did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that we used #pragma pack(1) in our code,
which means the bools in the DOMParser are packed down to 1 byte, whereas Xerces doesn't #pragma pack and gets the default packing of 4 bytes.

Answer (score 17):

I took your code, as is, and added:

```
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <iostream>
```

then renamed the function to main() and compiled it on x86-64 Fedora 22, which has libxml2 2.9.2

The resulting code ran successfully, using the sample file, with no segfaults. Even [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) found no memory access violation. As proof, the resulting, abbreviated strace log is as follows:

```
stat("Pin.xml", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=362, ...}) = 0
stat("Pin.xml", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=362, ...}) = 0
stat("Pin.xml", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=362, ...}) = 0
open("Pin.xml", O_RDONLY)               = 3
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
read(3, "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n\n<servers>\n\n<server_info>\n\n    <server_name>Server1</server_name>\n\n    <server_ip>127.0.0.1</server_ip> \n\n    <server_data_port>9000</server_data_port> \n\n</server_info>\n\n<server_info>\n\n    <server_name>Server2</server_name> \n\n    <ser"..., 8192) = 362
read(3, "", 7830)                       = 0
getcwd("/tmp", 1024)                    = 5
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Although this is Fedora with slightly new libxml2 and gcc, this difference does not matter. The answer here is that there's nothing wrong with the code that's shown here. I see nothing wrong with it.

But it is obviously a part of a much larger application, and your memory corruption is happening in some other part of your application, and it only manifests itself when your application's execution reaches this part.

The thing about C++ is that just because the code crashes at a particular point, it doesn't mean that this particular line of code is where the problem is. It shouldn't be too hard to come up with a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{

    char foo[3];

    strcpy(foo, "FoobarbazXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

    for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The bug here obviously occurs in the `strcpy` line. But the code will run just fine, and print 100 numbers from 0 to 99, and crash when main() returns. But, obviously, "return 0" is not where the bug is.

This is analogous to what's happening with your application. Some kind of memory corruption occurs at some point, which doesn't materially affect code execution until your code tries to parse your XML file.

Welcome to C++.

Comment: Thanks, It did not cross my mind that the problem could be coming from elsewhere. Just a quick follow up, Is there any way to recompile the code to change the point where the memory violation occurs?

Comment: The thing about corrupting memory is that the results are unpredictable, and there are no rules or guidelines to follow, whatsoever. There is, truly, no simple, paint-by-numbers, recipe or process for tracking down and locating the real bug. Typical things I try in these kinds of situations is to use a static analysis tool like valgrind, or temporary changing the code logic to skip large sections of code that normally gets executed, to see if the memory corruption goes away. It all comes down to experience, knowledge, and understanding how the CPU runs code, and how your application works.